# How to handle multiple sub-elements in PHP DOMXPath?

Tags: php, html, xpath, domxpath

I'd like to import an HTML document onto a MySQL database using PHP.

The structure of the document looks like this :

```
<p class="word">
<span class="word-text">word1</span>
<span class="grammatical-type">noun</span>
</p>
...
<p class="word">
<span class="word-text">word128</span>
<span class="grammatical-type">adjective</span>
</p>
```

For each *word*, I only have one *word-text* and one *grammatical-type*.

I'm able to find each *word* node, but for each of its children *word-text* and *grammatical-type* I'd like to perform a MySQL query :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
            $dom->loadHTMLFile($location);
            $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
            $res = $xpath->query("//p[@class='word']");
            foreach ($res as $textNode) {
                //do something here for each *word-text*->nodeValue
                //do something here for each *grammatical-type*->nodeValue
                }
            }
```

I tried in the `foreach` loop to pass `$textNode`, which is a *DOMNode*,  as a `$contextNode` as follows :

```
$wordText = $xpath->query("span[@class='word-text']", $textNode);
$myWord = $wordText->nodeValue;
```

But in $wordText I only have a *DOMNodeList* with a NULL *nodeValue*.

How can I, starting from the *word* node, manage the children nodes ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

You just need to, as you know that the `node` only contains a single element, select this single element using `item(0)` :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
            $dom->loadHTMLFile($location);
            $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
            $res = $xpath->query("//p[@class='word']");
            foreach ($res as $textNode) {
                $wordTextNode = $xpath->query("span[@class='word-text']", $textNode);
                $word = $wordTextNode->item(0)->nodeValue;

                //do same thing here for each *grammatical-type*
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide different node as context in your `$xpath->query` calls:

```php
<?php

$location = 'so-dom.html';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
            $dom->loadHTMLFile($location);
            $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
            $res = $xpath->query("//p[@class='word']");
            foreach ($res as $textNode) {
                echo $xpath->query('./a/text()', $textNode)[0]->nodeValue;
                                                //^^^^^^^^^
                };

?>
```

Where doc is

```html
<head></head>
<body>
  <p class="word"><a>one</a></p>
  <p class="word"><a>two</a></p>
</body>
```

will print "onetwo"